# What's a good way to describe "everything", when that "everything" is very little?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-requests

I thought about describing it this way:

> ...which led to his loss of the little of everything he had.

It doesn't sound very nice, and it also sounds like I'm saying that the loss was a "little of everything."

Is there a better way to describe this?

Comment: ..which led to the loss of the *precious little* he possessed?

Comment: ..which led to lossing the very little that he never had anything beside.

Comment: *... losing all of what little he had.* By the *little of everything* could actually mean a small part of each of the things he had, not all! (The definite article does help, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just remove the "of everything" and possibly change the "his" to a "the"

> ...which led to the loss of the little he had.

Comment: +1 Or if it were tangible objects, *... the few things he had*.

Answer (score 0):

'Which led to the entire loss of his few humble possessions'.

Answer (score 0):

...which led to his loss of everything, yet it was so little.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: With all due respect, I sincerely believe that my answer is "a good way" to describe 'everything', when that 'everything' is very little. Isn't writing what you thought originally a good way to write? --Note: If I want to write that in my essay, I would go with "...which led to his loss of everything, yet his loss was so little."

Answer (score -1):

"the loss of what little he had"

or perhaps, to put a finer point on it, "the loss of what little he did have."